# Preload dependencies recursively using link rel="modulepreload"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, es6-modules, preload

I would like to trigger recursive javacript module preload (preload a script and all its dependencies/imports).

Docs mention that:

The  spec actually allows for optionally loading not just the requested module, but all of its dependency tree as well. Browsers don't have to do this, but they can.
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/modulepreload/#but-what-about-modules-dependencies

Chrome doesn't do that - the module specified in href gets preloaded but its dependencies - do not.

Can I force a recursive preload of all dependencies?
Are there browsers that support this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran tests. I used `link="modulepreload"` in `<head>` for a module with 3 dependencies, two levels deep. I then ran synchronous javascript before importing the preloaded module in a `<script type="module">`, this to get a gap in the timeline to be able to distinguish preloading from regular loading.

To achieve the gap I tested two methods.

1. alert()
2. while loop running 1000 ms

I also ran tests without importing the module, only preloading it.

*Results:*

**Firefox v118:**
Test method | Result
--- | ---
alert() | Preloaded all dependencies
while loop 1000 ms | Preloaded only module
without import | Preloaded all dependencies

**Chrome v117 and Safari v17.0:**
Test method | Result
--- | ---
alert() | Preloaded only module
while loop 1000 ms | Preloaded only module
without import | Preloaded only module

Currently only Firefox does sometimes preload all dependencies and my guess is that is depends on whether it has time to do it, that would explain why it did not preloaded the dependencies when it was busy running the while loop.